# How to add a custom JAR file to CLASSPATH when running gradle from command line?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25923405/184184) except that, how to do this for Gradle?

I have placed cucumber-android and some other JAR files related to cucumber in my app/libs directory. This is part of my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
   dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.19.2'
    classpath fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
  }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

When I run a cucumber feature test from Android Studio, it runs successfully, because Android Studio automatically includes the files in the libs directory into CLASSPATH.

When I run the test from command line using

```
./gradlew --info cC
```

I get the error:

> cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: No backends were found. Please make sure you have a backend module on your CLASSPATH.

This is because the JAR files in the libs are not in the CLASSPATH. How do I include JAR files when running cc in gradle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove the `@RunWith(Cucumber.class)` annotation from the class that has `@CucumberOptions` annotation.