# Exception in thread "main" cucumber.runtime.CucumberException:

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

When I run my Cucumber feature file I am getting following error:

> Exception in thread "main" cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: No
>   backends were found. Please make sure you have a backend module on
>   your CLASSPATH.

I added all latest dependencies.

What is the problem and how can I solve this?

Comment: Refer this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25923405/exception-in-thread-main-cucumber-runtime-cucumberexception-no-backends-were](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25923405/exception-in-thread-main-cucumber-runtime-cucumberexception-no-backends-were)

Comment: @Eknath i check with the above solutions.I didnt find any problem with the path and the dependencies.Still the script is failing

Comment: can u share the dependencies that u added to the project ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you still need this to be Answered. But might be useful for other if found same problem. I recently got this very same issue resolved just by adding Cucumber-Java dependency to my project(i.e. POM.xml).
Note: I already had- jUnit & Cucumber-core Dependency added, only this one was missing.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

below dependencies should be added-

```
<groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
--
<groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
```