# No backends were found. Please make sure you have a backend module on your CLASSPATH. How do I resolve this error

Tags: java, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

```
<version.cucumber>3.0.2</version.cucumber>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${version.cucumber}</version>
</dependency>
```

I have the following dependencies already added to my POM. Yet, when I try to run my cucumber tests in a unix environment using jdk1.8.0 update 202, I get the above mentioned errors. All the sites I have visited suggest adding all sorts of dependencies. I believe I already have the dependencies. I was running fine earlier with jdk1.8.0 update 121 but due to some certificate issues I had to update it to update 202 and now I can't get it working with the previous jdk version also. Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25923405/exception-in-thread-main-cucumber-runtime-cucumberexception-no-backends-were

Comment: Yes, I have. It does not work @JulienRevaultd'A...

Comment: Try to add (not java-8 or both) :  <dependency>
       <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
       <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
       <version>4.2.6</version>
   </dependency>

Comment: I need java8 because I am using lambda expressions. Is there a way to keep that, if not the effort required to change  everything would not be feasible. And without the junit dependency I get compile errors@JulienRevaultd'A...

Comment: I don't think you will have to change anything on your code with the cucumber-java dependency, and both dependencies can be altogether. The java-8 dependency just adds a few instructions and may lack some others... Give it a try

Comment: cucumber-java8 dependency supports the lambda expression format for steps definition. without the 8 i just get compile errors as such:

````
cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method Then(java.lang.String,(Long mlqA[...]]); })
@JulienRevaultd'A...

Comment: Did you try with both ?

Comment: Just tried it with both, still does not work :( @JulienRevaultd'A...

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that `cucumber-java` from `io.cucumber` dependency must be a valid one. Once I deleted it worked but I still needed for info on the console. Here is the ones I used together:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok beware of your different versions, you have both 3.0.2 and 4.2.6 :

```
<version.cucumber>3.0.2</version.cucumber>
<version>4.2.6</version>
```

Rewrite like this :

```
<version.cucumber>4.2.6</version.cucumber>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
    <version>${version.cucumber}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>${version.cucumber}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I tried this out too, its still not working. I am still getting the no backends were found error. Is java8 lambda syntax not compatible with jdk1.8?

Comment: Also, with this, I am no longer able to view my features file. I am getting a null pointer exception.

Comment: Do you think you could extract a reproducable error in a small project so I could have a look ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issues and it  happened because cucumber jars were not downloaded properly. This was resolved after force updating maven project. Also Please make sure your project is converted to cucumber project.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).